# How can get selected value in Spinner using Model class?

Tags: java, android, spinner

I created a form with Spinner and I saved all value into `SQLite Database` , I am getting all the saved values from database using `SQL Query`  and `Model Class` on `Edit Text` and `Text Views` but I dont know how can I get database selected value on Spinner which is stored in `Databbase` ?

I already saved value into database but when I going to update page all the values are showing instead of spinner.
I am getting all the values in `edit text` but how can I get value into `spinner`?

```
 EditText  name = findViewById(R.id.name);
 EditText email = findViewById(R.id.email);
 EditText phone_no = findViewById(R.id.phone_no);    
 Spinner country = findViewById(R.id.country);

    name.setText(model.getname());
    email.setText(model.getemail());
    phone_no.setText(model.getphone());
```

There is no error messages please help me.

Comment: You have to `setAdapter` as `ArrayList<String>` for spinner

Comment: I already saved value into database but when I going to update page all the values are showing instead of spinner.

Comment: show code where spinner is load

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
    spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener{
       @Override
       public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
         viewModel.setValue(position);
       }
   });
```

And in ViewModel:

```
private List<Item> list = // some array with values
private Item selected;

public void setValue(int position){
    selected = list.get(position);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

you can Comparison between value than returned by database (i call it value in code) and each item of your spinner and select that itam  has same text with value

```
    String value = "getted value from db";

    Spinner spinner = findViewById(R.id.spinner);

    for (int i = 0; i < spinner.getAdapter().getCount(); i++) {
        if (value == spinner.getAdapter().getItem(i)) {
            spinner.setSelection(i);
        }
    }
```